# how to store a json string value in year[i] using the for loop in android studio?

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

this is my json

```
{
    "user_data": [
        {
            "year": "2017",
            "month": "12",
            "day": "12",
            "StartTime": "2:00 am",
            "Endtime": "4:00 am",
            "Hours": "02:00:00"
        },
        {
            "year": "2018",
            "month": "12",
            "day": "10",
            "StartTime": "5:00 am",
            "Endtime": "7:00 am",
            "Hours": "02:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I retrieve the data using the php and send them to the android activity, but the problem is, in android activity i was able to retrieve the result using the for loop but when i tried to put them in toast it display the last row details from JSON. So i tried to put them in `array[]`,so that i can retrieve the data one by one `array[0]`,`array[1]`,using the for loop, but when i try to run the app in emulator the application get closed.can any one help me to print the data one by one using the array[]?

this is my main activity

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText name, password;
    String NAME=null, PASSWORD=null, EMAIL=null;
    String Name, Password;
    Context ctx=this;
    String[] year[];
    String[] month;
    String[] day;
    String[] StartTime;
    String[] Endtime;
    String[] Hours;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_name);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_password);
    }


    public void main_login(View v){
        Name = name.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();
        BackGround b = new BackGround();
        b.execute(Name, Password);
    }

    class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
            String data="";
            int tmp;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/sample/FETCH/fetch.php");
                String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                    data+= (char)tmp;
                }

                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return data;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try
            {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray user_data = root.getJSONArray("user_data");

                for (int i = 0; i < user_data.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = user_data.getJSONObject(i);

                    year[i]= jsonObject.getString("year");
                    month[i]  = jsonObject.getString("month");
                    day[i]  = jsonObject.getString("day");
                    StartTime[i]  = jsonObject.getString("StartTime");
                    Endtime[i]  = jsonObject.getString("Endtime");
                     Hours[i]  = jsonObject.getString("Hours");



                }


                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result has value" + year[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(result==null)
            {
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, year[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else
                {

                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result has value"+ year[0]  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

did i done anything worng in coding?

this is the error i am getting

```
01-02 11:19:26.576 12979-12979/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 12979
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$BackGround.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:108)
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$BackGround.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:58)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Can you show the error log?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result has value" + year[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` this will always show first value  because of `year[0]`

Comment: @charitha i had edited ! please see my logcat

Comment: May be your JsonArray is null

Comment: @ alive ,ya you are correct but it not showing,the app is getting closed,i dont know weather i had done any mistake in coding part are any other problem in storing the value in array[]

Comment: @nd1010,i am reciving the data from the database i had checked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Actually there are two errors:-***

1.`String[] year[]; //wrong declaration`

2.`String[] month; // need to be initialized inside onPostExecute and same for others`

***Solution:-***

You need to convert:-

```
String[] year[]; //wrong declaration
```

To:-

```
String[] year;
```

***And inside `protected void onPostExecute(String result) {` do this:-***

```
year = new String[user_data.length];
month = new String[user_data.length];
day = new String[user_data.length];
StartTime = new String[user_data.length];
Endtime = new String[user_data.length];
Hours = new String[user_data.length];
```

***Note:- Also i think that***

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result has value" + year[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

***Need to be inside `for` loop and will be like this:-***

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result has value" + year[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks @ alive to die
it is working.
but we cannot able to declear user_data.length below public class MainActivity extends Activity .

so i declear it in post execude it worked.

Comment: @selvasurya  glad to help you. :):)

Comment: @selvasurya  yes i have edited that part. check now and let me know if anything missed

Answer (score 3):

There are two issue first is

```
String[] year[];
```

**it's**

```
String[] year;
```

second, you have not initialized the array

```
year=new String[user_data.length()];
month=new String[user_data.length()];
day=new String[user_data.length()];
StartTime=new String[user_data.length()];
Hours=new String[user_data.length()];
```

Comment: @selvasurya can you edit the question with updated one and LOG?

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to initialize the arrays.

```
  JSONArray user_data = root.getJSONArray("user_data");
```

add the code below before the for loop in the postexecute method

```
            year = new String[user_data.length()];
            month = new String[user_data.length()];
            day = new String[user_data.length()];
            StartTime = new String[user_data.length()];
            Hours = new String[user_data.length()];
```

Comment: no its not working the app is getting closed again. :(

Comment: also declare variables properly   String[] year[];->  String year[];

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below pattern, Create a new class `Example`

```
public class Example {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example{" +
                "year='" + year + '\'' +
                ", month='" + month + '\'' +
                ", day='" + day + '\'' +
                ", startTime='" + startTime + '\'' +
                ", endTime='" + endTime + '\'' +
                ", hours='" + hours + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    private String year;
    private String month;
    private String day;
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;
    private String hours;

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public String getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(String hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }
}
```

Now onPost method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    List<Example> examples = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = root.getJSONArray("user_data");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Example example = new Example();
            example.setYear(jsonObject.getString("year"));
            example.setMonth(jsonObject.getString("month"));
            /*...set other variables...*/
            example.setHours(jsonObject.getString("Hours"));
            examples.add(example);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RESULT: " + example.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete answer, please go through it. Also checked the output.

**Output :**

**result has value2017**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText name, password;
    String NAME = null, PASSWORD = null, EMAIL = null;
    String Name, Password;
    Context ctx = this;
    String[] year;
    String[] month;
    String[] day;
    String[] StartTime;
    String[] Endtime;
    String[] Hours;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_name);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_password);
    }


    public void main_login(View v) {
        Name = name.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();
        BackGround b = new BackGround();
        b.execute(Name, Password);
    }

    class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
            String data = "";
            int tmp;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/sample/FETCH/fetch.php");
                String urlParams = "name=" + name + "&password=" + password;

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                while ((tmp = is.read()) != -1) {
                    data += (char) tmp;
                }

                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return data;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray user_data = root.getJSONArray("user_data");

                year = new String[user_data.length()];
                month = new String[user_data.length()];
                day = new String[user_data.length()];
                StartTime = new String[user_data.length()];
                Endtime = new String[user_data.length()];
                Hours = new String[user_data.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < user_data.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = user_data.getJSONObject(i);

                    year[i] = jsonObject.getString("year");
                    month[i] = jsonObject.getString("month");
                    day[i] = jsonObject.getString("day");
                    StartTime[i] = jsonObject.getString("StartTime");
                    Endtime[i] = jsonObject.getString("Endtime");
                    Hours[i] = jsonObject.getString("Hours");
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result has value" + year[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct this:

```
String[] year[]; //wrong declaration
```

to

```
String[] year;
```

before insert data to string array initialize first.

```
year = new String[user_data.length];
month=new String[user_data.length];
day=new String[user_data.length];
StartTime=new String[user_data.length];
Hours=new String[user_data.length];
```

Happy coding!!